# Recursive function not properly evaluating keys in objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two objects, of identical length and having identical keys. The only difference is that those keys may have different values. The problem is that the method that is supposed evaluate both objects, breaks -- I've spent hours trying to figure this one out.

Here is `originalReference`:

```
{  
   "id":68,
   "article_id":12338,
   "article_reference_id":68,
   "article_reference_extraction_id":667320,
   "user_id":null,
   "file":"1238-230180-1-CE.doc",
   "revision":1,
   "order":1,
   "type":"journal",
   "preview":"Chewning B, Bylund CL, Shah B, Arora NK, Gueguen JA, Makoul G. Patient preferences for shared decisions: a systematic review. Patient Educ Couns 2012 Jan; 86(1):9-18",
   "status":1,
   "source":"Unknown",
   "data":{  
      "pii":"S0738-3991(11)00114-5",
      "webciteId":null,
      "publication":[  

      ],
      "conference":[  

      ],
      "authors":[  
         {  
            "firstName":"B",
            "lastName":"Chewning"
         },
         {  
            "firstName":"CL",
            "lastName":"Bylund"
         },
         {  
            "firstName":"B",
            "lastName":"Shah"
         },
         {  
            "firstName":"NK",
            "lastName":"Arora"
         },
         {  
            "firstName":"JA",
            "lastName":"Gueguen"
         },
         {  
            "firstName":"G",
            "lastName":"Makoul"
         }
      ],
      "editors":[  
         {  
            "firstName":"G",
            "lastName":"Makoul"
         }
      ],
      "comments":[  

      ],
      "source":{  
         "title":"Patient Educ Couns",
         "date":{  
            "year":"2012",
            "month":"01",
            "day":null
         },
         "pages":{  
            "from":"9",
            "to":"18"
         },
         "volume":"86",
         "issue":"1",
         "url":"http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/21474265"
      },
      "accessDate":null,
      "articleTitle":"Patient preferences for shared decisions: a systematic review"
   },
   "doi":"10.1016/j.pec.2011.02.004",
   "pmid":21474265,
   "pmcid":null,
   "isbn":"",
   "created_at":"2019-04-09 10:04:53",
   "updated_at":"2019-04-09 10:04:53",
   "deleted_at":null,
   "max_revision":30,
   "extraction":{  
      "id":667320,
      "article_id":12338,
      "file":"1238-230180-1-CE.doc",
      "order":1,
      "original":"Chewning B, Bylund CL, Shah B, Arora NK, Gueguen JA, Makoul G. Patient preferences for shared decisions: A systematic review. Patient Educ Couns [Internet] Elsevier Ireland Ltd; 2012;86(1):9?18. PMID:21474265",
      "doi":null,
      "pmid":null,
      "isbn":null,
      "parsed":1,
      "created_at":"2019-02-25 18:40:46",
      "updated_at":"2019-02-25 18:40:46",
      "deleted_at":null
   }
}
```

---

And here is `reference`:

```
{  
   "id":68,
   "article_id":12338,
   "article_reference_id":68,
   "article_reference_extraction_id":667320,
   "user_id":null,
   "file":"1238-230180-1-CE.doc",
   "revision":1,
   "order":1,
   "type":"journal",
   "preview":"Chewning B, Bylund CL, Shah B, Arora NK, Gueguen JA, Makoul G. Patient preferences for shared decisions: a systematic review. Patient Educ Couns 2012 Jan; 86(1):9-18",
   "status":1,
   "source":"Unknown",
   "data":{  
      "pii":" ",
      "webciteId":null,
      "publication":[  

      ],
      "conference":[  

      ],
      "authors":[  
         {  
            "lastName":"Chewning",
            "firstName":"Betty"
         },
         {  
            "lastName":"Bylund",
            "firstName":"Carma L."
         },
         {  
            "lastName":"Shah",
            "firstName":"Bupendra"
         },
         {  
            "lastName":"Arora",
            "firstName":"Neeraj K."
         },
         {  
            "lastName":"Gueguen",
            "firstName":"Jennifer A."
         },
         {  
            "lastName":null,
            "firstName":" "
         }
      ],
      "editors":[  
         {  
            "firstName":"G",
            "lastName":"Makoul"
         }
      ],
      "comments":[  

      ],
      "source":{  
         "title":"Patient Education and Counseling",
         "date":{  
            "year":2012,
            "month":1,
            "day":null
         },
         "pages":{  
            "from":"9",
            "to":"18"
         },
         "volume":"86",
         "issue":"1",
         "url":"http://europepmc.org/abstract/MED/21474265"
      },
      "accessDate":null,
      "articleTitle":"Patient preferences for shared decisions: A systematic review"
   },
   "doi":"10.1016/j.pec.2011.02.004",
   "pmid":21474265,
   "pmcid":null,
   "isbn":"",
   "created_at":"2019-04-09 10:04:53",
   "updated_at":"2019-04-09 10:04:53",
   "deleted_at":null,
   "max_revision":30,
   "extraction":{  
      "id":667320,
      "article_id":12338,
      "file":"1238-230180-1-CE.doc",
      "order":1,
      "original":"Chewning B, Bylund CL, Shah B, Arora NK, Gueguen JA, Makoul G. Patient preferences for shared decisions: A systematic review. Patient Educ Couns [Internet] Elsevier Ireland Ltd; 2012;86(1):9?18. PMID:21474265",
      "doi":null,
      "pmid":null,
      "isbn":null,
      "parsed":1,
      "created_at":"2019-02-25 18:40:46",
      "updated_at":"2019-02-25 18:40:46",
      "deleted_at":null
   }
}
```

Notice how `articleTitle` in `originalReference` has typos, but `articleTitle` in `reference` has the correct title.

The point of the below function is to ensure that if `originalReference` previously had a non-empty/non-null/defined value for a key, `reference` shouldn't overwrite the value in `originalReference`.

And here is the function that evaluates both.

What's happening is that it throws an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'articleTitle' of undefined` when they're both clearly defined. Not sure what is happening.

Here's is the function:

```
evaluateEmptyValues: function(reference, originalReference) {
    var vm = this;

    console.log('reference', reference);
    console.log('Before   --> ' + reference.data.articleTitle);

    // Get keys and values of both reference objects
    referenceLength = Object.entries(reference).length;
    originalReferenceLength = Object.entries(originalReference).length;

    if (referenceLength == originalReferenceLength) {
        try {
            for (var prop in reference) {
                    if (reference[prop] != undefined || reference[prop] != null) {
                        if (typeof (reference[prop]) == 'string' && reference[prop].trim() == '') {
                            reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                        }

                        if (typeof(reference[prop]) == 'object' && typeof(originalReference[prop]) == 'object') {
                            console.log('reference[prop]', reference[prop]);
                            console.log('originalReference[prop]', originalReference);
                            vm.evaluateEmptyValues(reference[prop], originalReference[prop]);
                        }

                        if (Array.isArray(reference[prop]) && typeof Array.isArray(originalReference[prop])) {
                            reference[prop].forEach((item, index) => vm.evaluateEmptyValues(item, originalReference[prop][index]));
                        }
                } else {
                    reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }

    console.log('After    --> ' + reference.data.articleTitle);
    //
    // console.log('Original --> ' + originalReference.data.articleTitle);
}
```

Comment: what do you want to get finally?

Comment: are you attempting a recusive merge ? because there is [`_.merge`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#merge) and [`_.mergeWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mergeWith)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your line

```
if (reference[prop] != undefined || reference[prop] != null) {
```

use an AND, like this?

```
if (reference[prop] != undefined && reference[prop] != null) {
```

Comment: No, because if either is true, I want it to hit the `else`. Perhaps `reference[prop]  == null`  or `reference[prop]  == undefined`.. but `originalReference[prop]` might not be, so I want to assign `reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];`. And if `originalReference[prop] == null || originalReference[prop] == undefined`, then that's fine too -- nothing has changed

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this:

```
evaluateEmptyValues: function(reference, originalReference) {
    var vm = this;

    // Get keys and values of both reference objects
    referenceLength = Object.entries(reference).length;
    originalReferenceLength = Object.entries(originalReference).length;

    if (referenceLength == originalReferenceLength) {
        try {
            for (var prop in reference) {
                if (reference[prop] != undefined || reference[prop] != null) {
                    if (typeof (reference[prop]) == 'string' && reference[prop].trim() == '') {
                        reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                    }

                    if (typeof(reference[prop]) == 'object' && typeof(originalReference[prop]) == 'object') {

                        var length = Object.keys(reference[prop]).length;
                        for (var property in reference[prop]) {
                            if (originalReference[prop][property] != undefined) {
                                if (originalReference[prop][property] != null) {
                                    // vm.evaluateEmptyValues(reference[prop][property], originalReference[prop][property]);
                                    for (var i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {
                                        if ((reference[prop][property] == null || reference[prop][property] == '') &&
                                            originalReference[prop][property] != null) {
                                            reference[prop][property] = originalReference[prop][property];
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (Array.isArray(reference[prop]) && typeof Array.isArray(originalReference[prop])) {
                        reference[prop].forEach((item, index) => vm.evaluateEmptyValues(item, originalReference[prop][index]));
                    }
                } else {
                    if (originalReference[prop] != undefined) {
                        if (originalReference[prop] != null) {
                            reference[prop] = originalReference[prop];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch(err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
},
```